# PIVOT a horizontal table with Totals

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a table that has data that holds a total amount for each month of sales and each column is split by month.

E.g.

```
InvJan | InvFeb | InvMar ... TotalInv | CrdJan | CrdFeb | CrdMar  ...TotalCrd
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 100   |   120  |   200  ...   420    |   0    |   140  |   30    ... 170
```

AS you can see all the columns read across. 
I want to be able to PIVOT then to look like this:

```
     |     INV            CRD 
------------------------------
JAN  |     100             0          
FEB  |     120            140
MAR  |     200             30 
 .   |      .              .
 .   |      .              .
 .   |
______________________________
TOTAL|     420            170
```

Can I do this using Pivots? I am not too experience with them...or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of data transformation columns into rows is known as UNPIVOT. Since you are using SQL Server 2008, you should be able to use `CROSS APPLY` to unpivot your columns in pairs:

```
select Mnth, Inv, Crd
from yourtable
cross apply
(
    values
        ('Jan', InvJan, CrdJan),
        ('Feb', InvFeb, CrdFeb),
        ('Mar', InvMar, CrdMar),
        ('Apr', InvApr, CrdApr),
        ('May', InvMay, CrdMay)
        -- insert more columns here
) c (Mnth, Inv, Crd);
```

Comment: I never knew about this method! But it works perfectly for what I need!! Thanks +1

Answer (score 1):

using 2 [`unpivot`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)s.

```
select replace(inv,'inv',''), invval, crdval
from
(select * from yourtable unpivot (invval for inv in (invjan,invfeb,invmar,totalinv)) u) u1
unpivot (crdval for crd in (crdjan,crdfeb,crdmar, totalcrd)) u2
where replace(inv,'inv','')=replace(crd,'crd','')
```

or you can use a `union`

```
select 'jan', invjan as inv, crdjan as crd from yourtable
union all select 'feb', invfeb, crdfeb from yourtable
union all select 'mar', invmar, crdmar from yourtable
...
```

Answer (score 1):

First define what is Inv and Crd:

```
SELECT 'Inv' as Types, InvJan AS Jan, InvFeb as Feb, InvMar as Mar
INTO #testTable
FROM @table
UNION
SELECT 'Crd' as Types, CrdJan AS Jan, CrdFeb as Feb, CrdMar as Mar
FROM @table
```

Then Unpivot this|

```
select months, Types, data
INTO #test2
from #testTable
unpivot
(
  data
  for months in (jan, Feb, Mar)
) u;
```

and after that put as you like

```
select * 
from #test2
pivot (SUM (data) for Types in (Inv, Crd)) as T
```